# Connecting to a raspberry pi simultaneously from more than one desktop PC

Tags: networking

Is it possible to make a simultaneous connection from two or more PC's with a raspberry PI? The connection is made after connecting the raspberry and the PC's to the same WLAN network.

Specifically, I want to monitor the network traffic on different devices that are connected to a network. For that, I need the raspberry to be able to access to the traffic information from all the devices.  I need also a computer that is able to read the collected data from the raspberry.

So, just one Raspberry should be enough for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can make as many simultaneous network connections as you want.

Comment: Look into wireshark or Snort.  You should be able to run either on the Pi, and be able to monitor your network without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the RPi to capture network traffic, you can certainly use tools like tcpdump, tshark and others to capture whatever the RPi sees. The problem is that, in a normally operating modern network, it may not see the traffic you're interested in.

If your devices (monitoring RPi, computers to be monitored) are on a switch, by default, you will only see unicast traffic to or from the RPI, and broadcast and multicast traffic between the other nodes. Traffic directed from one other computer to another will not be seen. That is how switches function. You may be able to configure a SPAN/monitor switch port to capture all traffic between ports or on a VLAN, but that requires a much more expensive managed switch as well as administrator access to it.

If you can connect all the computers to be monitored onto a hub that the RPi is connected to, you will see all traffic. However, hubs are increasingly hard to find. You may be able to find a used 100 Mbps hub somewhere.

If you want to monitor a wireless network, a lot will depend on the capabilities of the wireless equipment. Some provides privacy features to prevent nodes from seeing each other directly.

If you can provide a more complete description of exactly what you want to do, we may be able to provide better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the rpi is slow and you can't monitor encrypted traffic, so there is likely a better way to fill whatever goal you have in mind.